# AngularJS function in controller and factory not working when separated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

```js
angular.module('myFirstApp')// 
//begin controller
.controller('myController',function($scope,$http,personFactory){ //hi im controller i need to call the http service from the factory 
  
  //begin service
  //hi im service i dont want to live in controller.js , i want to live in app.js
  //can we put the service inside a factory which is in app.js file and get called using controller #1
   $http.get('iphone.json').success(function(result){
    $scope.ObjectArray = result;
    
  }).error(function(error){
    alert(error.error + "/" + error.statusCode);
  }); //end
 
  
  //begin
  // hi i am controller #1 , i live in controller.js , i need to call http service in factory and send the value to HTML
   $scope.retrieveRecords = function(){
    var x = personFactory.getData();
    return x 
  }//end
  
  
  // i am controller #2
  $scope.addRecord = function(){
    var x = personFactory.insertData($scope.Name,$scope.Email,$scope.Password,$scope.Mobile,$scope.result);
    $scope.message = "You have successfuly added new data";
    return x + ' ' + $scope.message;
  }
  
  // i am controller #3
  $scope.editRecord = function(){
    var x = personFactory.updateData();
    $scope.message = "You have successfuly updated the data";
  return x + ' ' + $scope.message;
  }


})

//end controller

//begin factory
.factory('personFactory',function(){ //hi im factory i live in app.js , im waiting for http service to live here
  //end factory
```

what i need so much , please answer with something clever, all i need is the service separated to controller , what else should i say why is not posting damn blalbalblbllbalbalblablalkjvlwakjvnklwavjnlkwanvwanviwbilawvwavawvas
vasvklwanvljabwjkabwv

Comment: viewData? Also notice that the $http request returns a Promise so you may need to assign the value to $scope.viewData differently like:
`personFactory.getData().then(function(data) { $scope.viewData = data});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your factory from `angular.module('myFirstApp',[]).factory` to `angular.module('myFirstApp').factory` i.e., use `angular.module('myFirstApp')` but not `angular.module('myFirstApp', [])`

Comment: sorry , i have a ngRoute in that so i cannot exclude it, ill modify my code to include routing

Comment: When you use angular.module('myFirstApp',[]), it is not a getter of the existing module rather it creates new. Just remove [] from your factory js file. It will work

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/w53VjZDFnuJnE7itp8vR?p=preview , can you show me a nice way of coding

Comment: In your plunker, you have defined factory in app.js which is correct but if you want to separate it and use the same module then you get that module only. If you use [], then you are not using the earlier module and your earlier dependencies will also be not referred correctly.

Comment: its not gonna be saved you dont have permission . can you pin point to me the errors please thank you

Comment: $http.get('iphone.json').success(function(result){
     $scope.ObjectArray = result;
    
   }).error(function(error){
     alert(error.error + "/" + error.statusCode);
   });   // First : I need to put this in the app factory Second : the controller will need to call the code above Third: the html will call the controller $scope.retrieveRecord = function(){
//call the code above which is in the factory 
  }

Answer (score 1):

`return {getData}` is not right syntax in service

```
angular.module('myFirstApp',[])
.factory('personFactory',function(){

    function getData(){       
      var x = $http.get('iphone.json').success(function(result){
      $scope.items = result;
      alert(result);
      }).error(function(error){
      alert(error.error + "/" + error.statusCode);
      })    
      return x;
    }
  return {
      getData: getData
   };
```